# Asible split the stdout_line into array element

Tags: ansible

When I use this code its printing hostname and ip address in two line.

```
- name: Store known hosts of 'all' the hosts in the inventory file
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    ssh_known_hosts_command: "ssh-keyscan -T 10"
    ssh_known_hosts_file: "{{ lookup('env','HOME') + '/.ssh/known_hosts' }}"
    ssh_known_hosts: "{{ groups['all'] }}"

  tasks:
  - name: For each host, find the ip
    shell: 'echo -e "{{ item }}\n`dig +short {{ item }}`"'
    with_items: "{{ ssh_known_hosts }}"
    register: ssh_known_host_results
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: print message
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item + ' test' }}"
    with_items: "{{ ssh_known_host_results.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list }}"
```

If I added logic to ignore the localhost

> when: not item == 'localhost'

, its not spliting the hostname and ip address as array line, it comes hostname & ip as one line.

```
- name: Store known hosts of 'all' the hosts in the inventory file
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    ssh_known_hosts_command: "ssh-keyscan -T 10"
    ssh_known_hosts_file: "{{ lookup('env','HOME') + '/.ssh/known_hosts' }}"
    ssh_known_hosts: "{{ groups['all'] }}"

  tasks:
  - name: For each host, find the ip
    shell: 'echo -e "{{ item }}\n`dig +short {{ item }}`"'
    with_items: "{{ ssh_known_hosts }}"
    when: not item == 'localhost'
    register: ssh_known_host_results
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: print message
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item + ' test' }}"
    with_items: "{{ ssh_known_host_results.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list }}"
```

How can I split array element with when condition?

thanks
SR

Comment: I bet this is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). For example, there is [dig](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#the-dns-lookup-dig) lookup.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov, my idea is to get the hostname and ip address and remove the old key entry from the know_hosts file and add the new key to known host file.  dig look up is not helping this scenario.

Comment: Here's possible solution for you: run `ssh-keyscan` for every host with the first task (to get current fingerprints), loop trough registered result and use `lineinfile` module to update known_hosts if required.

Comment: yeah, I have the logic in place. host file will have the hostname, I want to find the ip address and key both ip and hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post this as answer, although this solves original task of maintaining know_hosts file in sync with actual fingerprints, and not OP's question "*How can I split array element with when condition?*":

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - command: ssh-keyscan -t rsa {{ item }} {{ lookup('dig',item) }}
      changed_when: false
      with_items: "{{ groups['all'] | difference(['localhost']) }}"
      register: current_keys

    - lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/hhh
        regexp: "^{{ item.split()[0] }}"
        line: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ current_keys.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list }}"
```

First task loops through all hosts in the inventory except localhost and fetches current rsa fingerprint of host and it's ip address.

Second task ensures that lines in destination file and fetched by ssh-keyscan matches.

Comment: this has few issues, if dns is not valid task fails, also if know_hosts has multiple lines its keeps the multiple lines for new keys.  my original scripts works on ansible 2.3.0.0. only lower version of ansible we are having the problem.